# I don't see all the questions in the "Tagged Questions" page

Tags: support

When I go to a tag page, I don't see all the questions that are tagged with that tag.
I notice it when going to a tag page with a low amount of tagged questions, like [head](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/head).

When I enter the page I see all the 7 questions and then 5 of them disappear quickly (after less than a second) and all I see, in this case, are the top question and the third question.

I was going to post it on the main site but thought that maybe it has to do with the site's functionality (although it's unlikely) so I posted it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often, this is caused by a preference: Open your profile by clicking your user name on the main site and go to *prefs* (or click [here](https://superuser.com/users/preferences/165729)) and remove the checkbox next to "Hide ignored tags".

In your case (you're logged in on Firefox, right?) this might be a user script (Greasemonkey, Ninjakit, etc.). Check out your locally set up scripts for anything SE/SU specific.

Comment: Yeah, it was the "Hide ignored tags" preference. It only worked on Firefox because it wasn't logged into my account in Firefox (so I surfed as a guest). Thanks for the help :)